# keep recieving access not configured when trying to access drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I would appreciate any help you can offer, as I'm at the end of my rope here.

I'm trying to access drive to upload a file.  I had this working from another workstation but now when at my primary station I am unable to proceed and keep receiving the same error:

```
06-05 14:15:31.801: E/Error(3691): FileException
06-05 14:15:31.801: E/Error(3691): com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
06-05 14:15:31.801: E/Error(3691): {
06-05 14:15:31.801: E/Error(3691):   "code": 403,
06-05 14:15:31.801: E/Error(3691):   "errors": [
06-05 14:15:31.801: E/Error(3691):     {
06-05 14:15:31.801: E/Error(3691):       "domain": "usageLimits",
06-05 14:15:31.801: E/Error(3691):       "message": "Access Not Configured",
06-05 14:15:31.801: E/Error(3691):       "reason": "accessNotConfigured"
06-05 14:15:31.801: E/Error(3691):     }
06-05 14:15:31.801: E/Error(3691):   ],
06-05 14:15:31.801: E/Error(3691):   "message": "Access Not Configured"
06-05 14:15:31.801: E/Error(3691): }
```

I've followed all the directions listed in https://developers.google.com/drive/ and like I said had this working.  I've also deleted the client ID from goodle's API Console. Infact I've scraped the whole project on the console and started over.

I have done so far:
* deleted project from api console
* enabled Drive SDK and API in console 
* regenerated client ID in console using SHA1 key from current work station

Is there some issue where I already interacted with google services on another machine?  I really am stumped here, any help/ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

working now....

fracking frack, didn't realize the package name field in the google api console was tied to the AndroidManifest.xml file...

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.name.package"  <--- this is the package name
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
```

Where marked by <--  this is the package name that is suppose to go into the google api console client ID package name field (see image)

[image: google api package name]